# python IMAP content of email contains a string

Tags: python, imap

I am able to log in a gmail account with python IMAP

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap.login(myDict["emailUsername"], myDict["emailPassword"])
imap.select(mailbox='inbox', readonly=False)
resp, items = imap.search(None, 'All')
email_ids = items[0].split()
latest_email_id = email_ids[-1]

resp, data = imap.fetch(latest_email_id, "(UID)")
print ("resp= ", resp, " data=", data)
#msg_uid = parse_uid(data[0])
match = pattern_uid.match(data[0].decode("utf-8"))
#print ("match= ", match)
msg_uid = match.group('uid')
```

I need to make sure that the UID for the last email I have contains a certain string (XYZ).  I am NOT looking for header subject but the content of email. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could go:

1. Fetch the message and walk through the text body parts looking for your string -- example at [Finding links in an emails body with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985722/finding-links-in-an-emails-body-with-python)
2. Get the server to do the search by supplying 'latest_email_id' and your search criteria back to the server in a UID SEARCH command. For Gmail, you can even use the X-GM-RAW attribute to use the same syntax support by the GMail web interface. See https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions for details of that.